# Prevent duplicated credit cards in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've setup WooCommerce on a site & added Stripe as a form of payment. In the users account section they can store credit card details but I've noticed that you can add the same credit card twice (I'm testing with the test credit card details stripe provide). Is there a way of preventing this? So only unique cards can be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not -- Stripe's payment method never stores actual numbers on your site, and instead 'tokenizes' the numbers into a unique hash. Therefore, you could never check entered numbers against an existing set, since they're never saved locally and aren't accessible via those tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I assumed this was the case but had hoped there was some way of doing it on Stripe's end.

Comment: I believe you can get the last 4 digits, so there'd be SOME check there. But that's not air-tight of course. Plus you'd have to build out your own Stripe add-on to work with WooCommerce to check for this sort of thing, but it might be worth it if this is a concern.

Comment: I was having a similar thought as, like you said, you do get the four digits back & the expiry date which I'm pretty sure make a unique combination - I think just the last four digits do but this bit of functionality isn't quite that important thankfully.